# Three.js - Is it possible to store BoxGeometries or MeshLambertMaterial in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, three.js

```
var taCubeGeometry = new Array();
var taCubeMaterial = new Array();

var taCubeGeometry.push(new THREE.BoxGeometry( .5, .5, .5));
var taCubeMaterial.push(new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "image.png" )}));
```

Is it possible to do it this way? Then later on store the geometry and meshLambertMaterial into a Mesh variable?

```
var taCube = new THREE.Mesh(taCubeGeometry[index], taCubeMaterial[index]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, you can do that. My IDE was complaining about it; but was a false alarm.